# jquery.ui sortable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a nested list with drag/drop functionality.  My issue is that I want each nesting to sort in itself. For example:

```
-first_level
-first_level
 -second_level
 -second_level
-first_level
```

"First level" should not be able to go into "Second Level" and vice versa.  I thought I could do this with the containment option but no dice there.  It works with keeping the second levels out of the first level but not the other way around.

Here is my example JS and list:

```
$("#sort_list").sortable({
  containment: '#sort_list',                                             
  axis: 'y',
  revert: true,
  items: 'li',
  opacity: 0.8
});
$(".sub_list").sortable({ 
  containment: 'parent',
  axis: 'y',
  revert: true,
  items: 'li',
  opacity: 0.8,
});
$("#sort_list").disableSelection();

<ul id="sort_list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ul class="sub_list">
    <li>sub one</li>
    <li>sub two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks guys!

Comment: I would be happy if it at least worked in FF.  Right now the current drag/drop functionality works in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like I found the problem.  I was declaring: items: 'li' and so it wasn't detecting the UL as a container/sortable item.  A big thanks to karim79 for helping me think all this through :)

Below is the working code (it's basically saying "Everyone stay in their own container"):

```
    $("#sort_list").sortable({
      containment: 'parent',                                                                                     
      axis: 'y',
      revert: true,
      opacity: 0.8
    });
    $(".sub_list").sortable({ 
      containment: 'parent',
      axis: 'y',
      revert: true,
      opacity: 0.8,
    });
    $("#sort_list").disableSelection();

    <ul id="sort_list">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two
        <ul class="sub_list">
        <li>sub one</li>
        <li>sub two</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
    </ul>
```

Now that we got the "item: li" thing sorted out we can even remove containment: 'parent', from the top list without fear of the lists colliding.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving the containment option a complex selector like:

```
$("#sort_list").sortable({
  containment: '#sort_list:not(.sub_list)',                                                                                     
  axis: 'y',
  revert: true,
  items: 'li',
  opacity: 0.8
});
```

That **should** do the trick if you're using jQuery 1.3+:

(from the [manual](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not))

> As of jQuery 1.3 :not() also support
>   selectors separated by commas and
>   complex selectors, for example:
>   :not(div a) and :not(div,a).

The jQuery Sortable manual says the [containment](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#option-containment) option:

> Constrains dragging to within the
>   bounds of the specified element - can
>   be a DOM element, 'parent',
>   'document', 'window', or a jQuery
>   selector.

Comment: If only it was that simple!  Ha, That's what I get for trying to write an example on the spot.  It's not an issue with the class names, as far as I can tell.

Comment: To be honest I'm pretty new to selectors, but I checked out the jquery API and they seem pretty straight forward.  I set up a quick demo with your suggested changes here http://www.stiprojects.com/sortable.html.  You can see how they just kind of slide together.  Also what is a bit frustrating is that using "containment" makes it hard to swith the top and bottom listings.